# How can I make DensityHistogram obey the lower bound in PlotRange in version 10?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

In version 9, `DensityHistogram` worked with `PlotRange` as expected:

```
SeedRandom[0]
DensityHistogram[
 Transpose[{RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], 
   RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000]}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}
]
```

[image]

In version 10, the upper bound (3) is obeyed (with some new padding) but the lower bound (0) is ignored:

[image]

How can I make DensityHistogram obey the lower bound in PlotRange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why PlotRange doesn't work (might need to report wolfram technical support), for workaround you could wrap it with Show:

```
SeedRandom[0]
Show[DensityHistogram[
  Transpose[{RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], 
    RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000]}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To get a plot very similar to the version 9 plot:

```
SeedRandom[0]
DensityHistogram[
 Transpose[{RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], 
  RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000]}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{-3.4, -1.4}, {-3.4, 0}}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: strangePadding]

Looks like a bug.

---

Specifying bin delimiters is an other option:

```
SeedRandom[0]
DensityHistogram[
 Transpose[{RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000], 
 RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000]}], {-0.5, 3.5, 0.5}]
```

[image: using bin delimiters]